# Some example how use stored procedure (add, edi, del) in MVC .NET application +LINQ

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, linq, storage, procedure

I look for some example how use the stored procedures in MVC with LINQ.

Comment: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/08/16/linq-to-sql-part-6-retrieving-data-using-stored-procedures.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to learn this would be to create a L2S dbml file.  Drag a table onto it and take a look at the code that it generates.

It's pretty simple to work out from there.  You can then call the dmbl class and use thing like `myConn.myObj.InsertOnSubmit(new myObj())` etc.

If you want to call a stored proc simply use ExecuteCommand to call the stored proc.  You can then fill your model directly off the result set.

I think, at this point though, that you need to just Google it a bit and then when you have more specific questions, come back to SO and ask those questions.

If you type "sql2linq stored proc" as the search string on this site you will also get a number of hits for this topic.